# VBA Text to column with xlDMYFormat in only one specific column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

The below code is working perfect for me, exept for one detail.
All my data end up in the appropriate columns with the right format, except for column D where they end up in US date format in stead of DMYFormat. Where in my code can I add DMYFormat for **only** column D? Or do I have to rewrite my code using array (I have no experience with array)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

My data in column A looks like this:

```
1111111;23E123000;1;08-09-2023;apple;pear;"banana";mango;kiwi;E_10100100;pos;;;;;;;;;;;;""
```

```
Sub TextToCol()

Sheets("ExampleA").Select
Dim ws As Worksheet, lrow As Long
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NGSimport")
With ws
    Sheets("ExampleA ").Select
    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    .Range("A1:A" & lrow).TextToColumns Semicolon:=True 
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `FieldInfo` argument of the `TextToColumns` method. `fieldinfo:=Array(Array(4, xlDMYFormat))`. As a matter of good practice, especially since `TextToColumns` will ***remember*** the last options used, you should set ***all*** of the arguments. And remember the Date format option should be set to the format of the date in the text string you are splitting; not the one you want on the Excel cell.

Comment: And also, depending on your windows regional settings, you may need to set the number format of that column to how you want to display it. Remember the text to columns option is based on how the value is stored in the CSV; the number format of the cell is based on how you want to see it displayed.

Comment: Thank you Ron Rosenfeld, I will try to rewrite my script with the FieldInfo argument.

Comment: You would be well served by setting the other arguments also. Especially the delimiters, both true and false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently came across a similar Q, see below may help. Mind the column D's date format.

```
Sub TextToCol()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NGSimport")

    With ws
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set dataRange = .Range("A1:A" & lrow)

        dataRange.TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, xlDMYFormat)), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        .Columns("D").NumberFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Excuse for my very late reply, I overlooked your answer. Thank you very much, this is very helpful

Comment: Glad it works, you're welcome @Caroline